# showing a real valued function is equivalently zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let a continuous $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\phi(t) \ge 0$. If $\phi(t) \le L\int_0^t \phi(s)\,ds $ for all $t \ge 0$, then why is $\phi \equiv 0$? ($L > 0$)

Comment: Look at Gronwall lemma.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Oh, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! It is a very useful tool.

Comment: Sorry, guys who feel shameful of this question and want to close it that I didn't meet the high standards of this community,. I tried to show it by myself, but sometimes I spend a lot of time without coming up with an idea or remembering well-known theorems. I have no one to ask around. I just wanted to get some help from brilliant minds on this web.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes, correct. I don't think I am used to it. However, this question helped me familiarize myself with Gronwall lemma!

Comment: It is good to know you got something out of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
\psi(t) := e^{-L t} \int_0^t \phi(s)\, ds, \qquad t\geq 0.
$$
Since $\phi$ is continuous, then $\psi$ is a $C^1$ function.
Moreover, $\psi(0) = 0$ and a direct computation shows that
$$
\psi'(t) = - L e^{-L t} \int_0^t \phi(s) ds + e^{-Lt} \phi(t) \leq 0,
\qquad \forall t\geq 0.
$$
Hence $\psi(t) \leq 0$ for every $t\geq 0$, so that
$$
\int_0^t \phi(s) ds \leq 0,
\qquad \forall t\geq 0.
$$
Since $\phi$ is continuous and $\phi\geq 0$, this last inequality implies that
$\phi(t) = 0$ for every $t\geq 0$.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much!