# Brezis' theorem 7.3: how does $\varphi (t) \le L \int_0^t \varphi (s) ds$ imply $\varphi \equiv 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, banach-spaces

I'm reading the proof of the uniqueness part of Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be a Banach space and $F:E \to E$ be $L$-Lipschitz for some $L>0$. Then given any $u_0 \in E$, there exists a unique solution $u \in C^1 ([0, \infty); E)$ of the problem
> $$
> (4) \quad\begin{cases}
> \frac{du}{dt} (t) &= F(u(t)) \quad \text{on} \quad [0, \infty), \\
> u(0) &= u_0.
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> **Proof**
> *Uniquness* Let $u, \overline u$ be two solutions of (4) and set
> $$
> \varphi (t) := |u (t) - \overline u (t)|
> \quad \forall t \ge 0.
> $$
> Then we have
> $$
> \varphi (t) \le L \int_0^t \varphi (s) ds
> \quad \forall t \ge 0, \quad (*)
> $$
> and consequently $\varphi \equiv 0$.

Could you please explain how the inequality $(*)$ implies $\varphi \equiv 0$?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3797514/42969

Comment: This is a special case of the integral form of [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grönwall%27s_inequality).

Comment: @MartinR Thank you so much for your help! The solution in your first link is very elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the solution replicated from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3797521/368425) thread.

---

Let
$$
\psi(t) := e^{-L t} \int_0^t \varphi(s) \, ds \quad t \ge 0.
$$

Because $\varphi$ is non-negative and continuous, we get $\psi \in C^1 ([0, \infty); \mathbb R_{\ge 0})$. Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align*}
\psi'(t) &= -Le^{-Lt} \int_0^t \varphi(s) \, ds + e^{-Lt} \varphi (t) \\
&= -L \psi (t) + e^{-Lt} \varphi (t) \\
&\le -L \psi (t) + Le^{-Lt} \int_0^t \varphi (s) \, ds \\
&= -L \psi (t) + L \psi (t) \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
$$

So $\psi$ is non-increasing. On the other hand, $\psi (0)=0$. Then $\psi \le 0$. On the other hand, $\psi$ is non-negative. Then $\psi \equiv 0$.